# Getting issue to generate Absolute Url's in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have created a mvc website which is working fine with localhost if i am coding something like this:

```
    <base href="http://localhost:5400/" />
    <li><a class="home" href="/Home/Index/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="wish"><a class="wishlist" href="/Products/Index/" id="wishlist-total">Products</a></li>
     <li><a class="account" href="/Home/Contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
```

But now to run it on live if i am trying to changing this:

```
  <base href="http://localhost:5400/" />
```

with this:

```
 <base href="HttpContext.Current.Request.Url" />
```

then its actually taking full root url everytime.So whenever i am clicking on any menu and moves to next menu it regain previous menu path also.

For this issue i tried below code which is also not working.

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Products",null,Request.Url.Scheme)">Products</a></li>
<li>  <a href="@Url.Action("Contact","Home",null,Request.Url.Scheme)">Contact</a></li>
```

According me this code will work,But if i am trying to pass "null"  as third parameter then i gives error:

ERROR: 'null' is not declared. 'Null' constant is no longer supported; use 'System.DBNull' instead.

Can someone please suggest what i should need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full stack trace when you get that exception?

Comment: Have you tried using `System.DBNull`?

Comment: That error has got nothing to do with the code you have shown. And why are you doing this  - you can just use `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")` or better, `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")` - the `<base>` tag is not required.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk  yes i tried with  system.dbnull.but its not working.

Comment: @StephenMuecke   yes i tried by removing <base> tag but still its retaining the first one on which i am clicking..e.g if i click on Contact first time it gives me correct url:   http://localhost:5423/Home/Contact              and after that if i click on Home..it gives me  wrong url:  http://localhost:5423/Home/Home/Index....its retiaing Home here...please  suggest me.

Comment: Have you removed the `null` and `Request.Url.Scheme` parameters

Comment: @StephenMuecke  yes  i tried by removing both.still same issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke   still now when i am clicking on HOME   url comes right and after that if i am clicking on Contact url become like this:   http://localhost:5423/Home/Home/Contact               its retaining Home  part still in url

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that behavior.Are you sure you are just using `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` or `@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "ActionName", "ControllerName")`  in **all** the views?

Comment: yes this is code i write.       <li>  <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a></li>
  <li>  <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Products")">Products</a></li>
  <li>  <a href="@Url.Action("Contact","Home")">Contact</a></li>                           both contact and home are in same view.

Comment: I can't see its possible to get that result. There must be some other issue with you code. Do you have any custom routes defined or are you using Areas?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix...

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home")
```

There's no need to enter `null` as a parameter... if you want to indicate that a parameter can be null, then you need to define that in the route its self, and if the parameter is missing, then it will know that the value is null implicitly...

```
// http://yoursite/Example/{id}
[Route("~/Example/{id}"] // Can't be null
public ActionResult Example(string id){ return View(); }

// http://yoursite/ExampleTwo/
[Route("~/ExampleTwo/{id?} // Can be null
public ActionResult ExampleTwo(string id) { return View(); }
```

TLDR if you want more errors...

1. Your issue is actually indicating a much larger issue... it looks as if you're accepting a query from a URI directly into a SQL query... if you are doing that, you're opening yourself up to injection attacks and as much as a part of me feels that anyone who does that pretty much has it coming to them... I can't stand by and just say nothing... sanitize **any** data that you receive from the user, no matter where it's coming from, [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)
2. Remove all those magic strings... you shouldn't have any strings such as the one you just displayed...

   ```
   // Bad...
   <a class="home" href="/Home/Index/">  

   // Better...
   <a class="home" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>

   // Good
   @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
   ```